# Nginx regular expression in location not working

Tags: nginx-config, nginx-location

The following RE matches "http://my.domain/video.mp4" successfully but cannot match "http://my.domain/abc/video.mp4".

```
    location ~ "^.+(mp4|mkv|m4a)$" {
        root /home/user/Videos;
    }
```

The log of Nginx reads

```
[05/May/2021:12:29:25 +0800] "GET /video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" status: 206, body_bytes: 1729881
[05/May/2021:12:29:46 +0800] "GET /abc/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" status: 404, body_bytes: 555
```

This is wired. Actually, I want URLs under "/service1/" to be mapped to user1's directory and URLs under "/service2" to be mapped to user2's. So I write

```
    location ~ "^/service1/.+(mp4|mkv|m4a)$" {
        root /home/user1/Videos;
    }
    location ~ "^/service2/.+(mp4|mkv|m4a)$" {
        root /home/user2/Videos;
    }
```

And as the first example, this config cannot match anything.

I searched a lot on google. No answer can explain this. I want to get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know where the problem is. In my second config, if I require "/service1/abcd.mp4", Nginx will try to locate it at "/home/user1/Videos/service1/abcd.mp4" but actually the file is at "/home/user1/Videos/abcd.mp4". Theoretically, I can bypass it by rewrite

```
location ~ "^/service1/.+(mp4|mkv|m4a)$" {
    rewrite "^/service1/(.+(mp4|mkv|m4a))$" "$1"; 
    root /home/user1/Videos;
}
location ~ "^/service2/.+(mp4|mkv|m4a)$" {
    rewrite "^/service2/(.+(mp4|mkv|m4a))$" "$1"; 
    root /home/user2/Videos;
}
```

But this is not working. I am getting crazy.